# Generate stubs for wso2 esb UsernameToken secured service

Tags: java, wso2, stub, wso2-esb

I am trying to write a simple java client for a wso2 esb service, secured using the UsernameToken method. I have difficulties generating the java stubs.

I've tried WSDL2Java first but it doesn't generate a valid pom.xml file and maven can't resolve the dependencies.

So I've decided to try and use JAX-WS RI instead. The stubs get generated and seem fine but I get the following exception when I try to invoke the service.

```
    Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching xxxxxx found
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at $Proxy32.getcodelists(Unknown Source)
    at com.sirmaitt.esb.codelists.client.Client.main(Client.java:32)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching xxxxxx found
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching xxxxx found
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 27 more
```

I understood the exception is caused by the self signed certificate the wso2 servers have. What can I do to avoid it?

Is there some easier way to generate valid java stubs for a ssl secured service using the UsernameToken security method? Here is my service definition:

```
 <proxy name="bala-ala" transports="https" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
        <target>
            <endpoint>
                <address uri="http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:9766/services/list?wsdl"/>
            </endpoint>
            <outSequence>
                <send/>
            </outSequence>
        </target>
        <publishWSDL uri="http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:9766/services/Codelists?wsdl"/>
        <policy key="conf:/repository/axis2/service-groups/bala-ala/services/bala-ala/policies/UTOverTransport"/>
        <enableSec/>
    </proxy>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use the wsdl exposed in http. (Service is exposed only in https but the wsdls are still exposed in http)

```
http://localhost:8280/services/bala-ala?wsdl
```

If you want to continue with the wsdl exposed in https, best option is to import the certificate of the ESB to cacerts.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I've tried importing the certificate but it didn't work. I guess this is because the CN are different? (ESB isn't running on localhost). How can I connect secure through the stub then? Is there some tutorial about this?

Comment: Either you have to upload a correct certificate to the ESB or you have to disable host name verification at the client end.